# Jquery toggle menu problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a sidebar that I want to appear, with a full screen fade over the whole page when I click the 'navigate' text.

I have it so that it appears, and my header text moves to the left, but how do I make it responsive so that when I quit the sidebar, my header reverts back and my fade goes away? I also can't get the fade to work when the sidebar appears.

Here is what I have:

my .js file:

```
    $(function() {
  $(".nav").click(function() {

    $(".sidebar").animate({width: 'toggle'});
    $('.fade').fadeIn();
    $(".cbp-af-header").animate({left: "-57px"}, 400);

  })  
})
```

Html:

```
<div class="nav">
<nav>
Click
</nav>

  </div>

    <div class="sidebar">
   <div class="nav">
<nav>
Click (So I can exit)
</nav>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="fade"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#fade {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.5; }


#fade { display: none; }

sidebar {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  position:fixed;
  background-color: #dafaea;
  z-index:1000;
  background:
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,rgba(102, 183, 176, 0.9), rgba(254, 240, 232, 1)), 
  url('http://i60.tinypic.com/21ke9u9.gif') center center;
  // background-size: cover; 218, 250, 234, 0.9



 }

.sidebar { display: none; }
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: I haven't worked it all out yet, but a couple of things I have found so far: 1) Your event handler is being attached to `.fade` instead of `#fade`, as soon as you fix that your grey background works. 2) Your `nav` elements are in `div`s with a class of `nav`. That is unnecessary. You can target a `nav` element in javascript and css, so I would remove the outer `div`s.

Comment: Have you seen http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/07/css-overlay-techniques/ ? There are a few techniques on there for setting up your backdrop. Once you get that worked out, the javascript should be pretty simple (see Eopin's answer below).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this with jQuery, you can try flagging your sidebar element (or any element really) with some sort of flag indicating whether it's shown or not, and have your click() function act differently depending on that flag.

You might end up with something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".nav").click(function() {
    // Just cacheing the sidebar element so that we don't query it every time
    var sidebar = $(".sidebar");

    if (sidebar.hasClass("visible")) {
        // Do stuff if the sidebar is visible: hide it, remove the .fade and mave the header back
        sidebar.animate({width: 'toggle'});
        $(".fade").fadeOut();
        $(".cbp-af-header").animate({left: "-57px"}, 400);

        // Remove the .visible class from .sidebar
        sidebar.removeClass("visible");
    }
    else {
        // Do stuff if the sidebar is not visible: show it and the .fade, and move the header
        sidebar.animate({width: 'toggle'});
        $(".fade").fadeIn();

        // Put the initial value of the left property of .cbp-af-header
        $(".cbp-af-header").animate({left: "0px"}, 400);

        // Tag the .sidebar with the .visible class
        sidebar.addClass("visible");
    }
  })  
})
```

Cheers